# DLL reference from .NETFramework developers pack

Tags: .net, dll, .net-framework-version

I have a class library project where few dll's are being referenced from, for example : **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Transactions.dll**

The location **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1** is installed from.NET Framework developers pack i think (since i have VS installed)

My question is, how this class library will be executed in a machine where **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1** has not been installed?

Answer (score 1):

If a referenced assembly cannot be found in the GAC or in the executables folder, you will receive a runtime exception like: `Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies`.

You have the following options:

- Deploy everything which is needed by your application to the target machine
- Install the developer pack manually
- Install the libraries in GAC manually

Typically the first option is the way to go.
Everything needed by your application should be in the /bin/Release folder after compile. If you copy the whole folder to another machine, the executable should start. Of course, .net runtime must be installed.